# No such module, swift, xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, header-files

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

.h module, as you can see, copied in project, but Xcode ignore it.
I'd try uninstall XCode and install 6.2 (beta 5),
In Terminal, I tried

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData ,
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode...
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using objective-c files, you need to add the `.h` file to your `Bridging-Header.h` file. This file was generated by Xcode itself but it's currently empty.

So open `Bridging-Header.h` and add the following line:

```
#import "QRCode.h"
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was thinking about something like that, but did not know how to apply. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Please add a header file and import the file.And the interfacing you need to do using Swift itself.

Answer (score 0):

You may just use the module without importing it because you dragged the swift file in your project rather than the binary.